# Conditional for Loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have following r code

```
x =c(1.7, 2.2,   14.4, 1.1,  .4, 20.6, 5.3, .7, 1.9, 13, 12, 9.3, 1.4, 18.7, 8.5, 25.5, 11.6, 
     14.1, 22.1, 1.1, 2.5, 14.4, 1.7, 37.6 ,.6, 2.2, 39, .3, 15, 11, 7.3, 22.9, 1.7, .1, 1.1, 
     .6, 9, 1.7, 7,  20.1, .4, 2.8, 14.1, 9.9, 10.4, 10.7, 30, 3.6, 5.6, 30.8, 13.3, 4.2, 25.5, 
     3.4, 11.9, 21.5, 27.6, 36.4, 2.7, 64, 1.5, 2.5, 27.4, 1, 27.1, 20.2, 16.8, 5.3, 9.7, 27.5, 
     2.5, 27)

n=length(x)

k=matrix(c(-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1), nrow=5, ncol=1)  

gamma=0.1               

lambda=matrix(c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), nrow=5, ncol=1)                 

    f<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=72, ncol=5)

for (i in 1:5)

{f[,i]<-((k[i,])*(.1^(k[i,])/(x^(k[i,]+1))))*((1-
  lambda[1])+2*lambda[1]*((.1/x)^(k[i,])))
}
```

Result of that function is based on different values of k and one value of lambda. What i want to do is to create a matrix of 25 by 72, and calculate the results based on different values of k and lambda. So the first five columns of the so called resulted matrix will be the results of k values and lambda first value, columns 6-10 will be results based on k values and second lambda value and so on.

Comment: Please edit your code fixing the indentation and adding spaces (and maybe a line break or two) inside your `for` loop. This will help a lot with readability. Also please try to make your code minimal - you load 5 packages at the top (and install 2 packages, one of which was loaded first ?) but you don't seem to use any of them. Please delete lines like that if they are irrelevant to your question and not needed to illustrate the problem. This also goes for lines like `mean(x)` - since you do not use the mean later, it seems this line is just clutter.

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a nested `for` loop is what is needed

```
x <- c(1.7, 2.2,   14.4, 1.1,  .4, 20.6, 5.3, .7, 1.9, 13, 12, 9.3, 1.4, 18.7, 8.5, 25.5, 11.6, 
     14.1, 22.1, 1.1, 2.5, 14.4, 1.7, 37.6 ,.6, 2.2, 39, .3, 15, 11, 7.3, 22.9, 1.7, .1, 1.1, 
     .6, 9, 1.7, 7,  20.1, .4, 2.8, 14.1, 9.9, 10.4, 10.7, 30, 3.6, 5.6, 30.8, 13.3, 4.2, 25.5, 
     3.4, 11.9, 21.5, 27.6, 36.4, 2.7, 64, 1.5, 2.5, 27.4, 1, 27.1, 20.2, 16.8, 5.3, 9.7, 27.5, 
     2.5, 27)
k <- c(-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1)
lambda <- c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1)                 
f <- matrix(, nrow = 72, ncol = 25)

for (i in seq_along(lambda)) {
  for (j in seq_along(k)) {
    f[, (i - 1) * 5 + j] <- k[j] * .1 ^ k[j] / x ^ (k[j] + 1) * (1 - lambda[i]) + 2 * lambda[i] * (.1 / x) ^ k[j]
  }
}
```

There might a way to write this with nested `sapply`, but this will likely be easier to follow since it is a fairly long equation